# Class 'my.example.Class' is compiled by a pre-release version of Kotlin and cannot be loaded by this version of the compiler

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ, I published a library but when I try to use it, I get the warning: `Class 'my.packge.MyClass' is compiled by a pre-release version of Kotlin and cannot be loaded by this version of the compiler`.
I am using the same `build.gradle.kts` on both projects, same kotlin version (1.6.21).
The weirdest part is that if I do `build`, the projects build just fine without any error.
Any suggestions on what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Seem to be Kotlin's bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21563

Watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.